# How to use cgi in the Apache htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to edit my .htaccess that any .test files will be treated as php
The Apache site tells something about cgi script
My question is how to do that?
Thx
.htaccess:
`Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
    # Turn mod_rewrite on 
    RewriteEngine On 
    ## hide .php extension 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] 
    #set path for error pages
    ErrorDocument 401 /401.php 
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.php 
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm .shtml .test
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm .shtml .test`

Comment: Well, "something"... Show your .htaccess and Apache output. It is Stackoverflow page, not Seeroverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update this in your .htaccess file:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm .shtml .test
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm .shtml .test
```

Comment: @ItaySharon updated my answer once again. I have tested it on my server its working. You just need to add the above lines to the `.htaccess` file,

Comment: You can go to itaysharon.esy.es/info.php for phpinfo();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104245/discussion-between-itay-sharon-and-fakhruddin-ujjainwala).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line into it:

```
Addhandler application/x-httpd-php .html .php .test
```